# DataContractSerializer works on Project A but Fails on Project B on Same Machine why?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I have a library which calls a DataContractSerializer.  I have been using it for many months in a ConsoleApp and a Windows Service App.  These were both created in Visual Studio 2015.

This week I created a new Win Forms App (in visual studio 2017) and I consume that .dll code.  Same code, same classes, same files - The 2 older projects still work, the new one throws this error.

**Note:** I am not using an app.config so all existing posts with that topic don't apply.  Also, I do not have a configSections or configuation node in my file, so those answers don't apply.

> {System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
>   system failed to initialize --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one
>    element allowed per config file and if present must
>   be the first child of the root  element.

The machine config's are the same cause they are all running on my machine.  So, I have no idea what else it might be.  Any ideas?

File which works correctly in my existing 2 projects starts with:

> ```
> > <SettingsModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> > xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model">   <SettingsList
> > xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
> >     <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringSettingsOFv3k_StQ>
> ```

Deserialization code which works for first 2 projects:

```
 using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
     stream.Position = 0;
     DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(GatewaySettingsModel));
     return deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as GatewaySettingsModel;
  }
```

**Edit**

*Config File for working app*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DataOption" value="5" />
  </appSettings>
  <entityFramework>
```

*Config file for non-working app*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="..." connectionString="..." />
    <add name="..." connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

As per the comment below and error text, the 'startup' tag had to be moved after the 'configurations' tag.  I don't understand why this error only was thrown for the DataContract Serialization, but this was the case.

Comment: Please include the config files for each of the applications.

Comment: @mjwills you're wise.

Answer (score 1):

As per [configSections Element (General Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation

> the configSections element is in a configuration file, the configSections element must be the first child element of the configuration element.

As a configuration file is configurable (you can add many sections and custom sections), the serializer needs to be able to understand these configuration sections, this requirement (that is first) removes problems like using a section before it handler is defined.